# Problems with a HTML design can someone tell me the failure in it?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm working on a project but my login shows I don't know why it is a little bit ugly, here is a picture: https://i.gyazo.com/c55e2edcd1fd2d18719e50eb67f1c817.png

I wasn't adding a database but can someone please say me why the password and the username fields are on different locations and not in `align=center`? Please  tell me the failure I was making.

Here is the code of my login page:

```js
(function() {
  'use strict'

  if (navigator.userAgent.match(/IEMobile\/10\.0/)) {
    var msViewportStyle = document.createElement('style')
    msViewportStyle.appendChild(
      document.createTextNode(
        '@-ms-viewport{width:auto!important}'
      )
    )
    document.head.appendChild(msViewportStyle)
  }

}())
```

```css
body {
  padding-top: 5rem;
}

.starter-template {
  padding: 3rem 1.5rem;
  text-align: center;
}

login {
  padding: 3rem 1.5rem;
  text-align: center;
  page-break-after: right;
}


/* Großes Display */

@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  ...
}


/* Tablet (Landschaft) */

@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 979px) {
  ...
}


/* Smartphones - Tablets */

@media (max-width: 767px) {
  ...
}


/* Smartphones und weniger */

@media (max-width: 480px) {
  ...
}
```

```html
<!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-PsH8R72JQ3SOdhVi3uxftmaW6Vc51MKb0q5P2rRUpPvrszuE4W1povHYgTpBfshb" crossorigin="anonymous">



<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-dark fixed-top">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navigation</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarsExampleDefault" aria-controls="navbarsExampleDefault" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarsExampleDefault">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="index.html">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="signup.html">Registrieren</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="signin.html">Anmelden</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="http://example.com" id="dropdown01" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Features</a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdown01">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="zfeatures.html">zuk&uuml;ntige Features</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="bfeatures.html">bestehenden Features</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="wuensche.html">W&uuml;nsche</a>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
      <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" placeholder="Suche" aria-label="Suche">
      <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Suchen</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</nav>

<div class="container">
  <div class="starter-template">
    <h1>Schulio Login</h1>
    <h6>Bitte melde dich an!</h6>
    <div class="login">
      <!-- Das ist der Loginbereich der Webapp-->
      <label for "username">Username</label>
      <input type="text" id="username" placeholder="Username">
      <br>
      <label for "password">Passwort</label>
      <input type="password" id="password" placeholder="Passwort  ">
      <br>
      <button type="submit" id="anmelden">Anmelden</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- /.container -->


<!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
        ================================================== -->
<!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-vFJXuSJphROIrBnz7yo7oB41mKfc8JzQZiCq4NCceLEaO4IHwicKwpJf9c9IpFgh" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-alpBpkh1PFOepccYVYDB4do5UnbKysX5WZXm3XxPqe5iKTfUKjNkCk9SaVuEZflJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: didn't you miss a dot in css? (.login)

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a dot in the css before login

```
.login {
    padding: 3rem 1.5rem;
    text-align: center; 
    page-break-after: right;}
```